# Create tab bar item that triggers Alert view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an `UITabBarController` and I want to create an item that will trigger only an alert view controller.

I want the alert to present on top of the view controller from which the button was pressed.

This is my code right now but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    if item.title == "Title"{
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in

            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        })
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Feature not active yet", message: "Will be added soon", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

it shows me the alert but will not move to index 0 in the OK action handler.

Comment: Provide more details supported by your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607988/tab-bar-shows-alert-message

Comment: I added some code, please see if you can tell what is the issue

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/pkesaj/TabbarItemAlert

Here you are example how can it work.

EDIT:

You need to add a UITabbarControllerDelegate and in the viewWillAppear add:

```
self.tabbarController?.delegate = self
```

then in body of class:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2{
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Do something", message: "With this", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "A thing", style: .default) { action in
        })
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I added my code ,I tried changing it to your didSelect but it won't work,Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you add UITabbarControllerDelegate after “:” and also did you put delegate = self into viewWillAppear?

Comment: @H.Epstein Make break point at .delegate = self and type in console “po self.tabbarcontroller” and it must be != nil. If it’s not nil then you have to check delegate is assigned in only one place.

Comment: @pkesaj this will always opens an alert as a background view of "tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0" ,How can I change this line so that it will be the previous selected index

Answer (score 0):

### @ Non-escaping And @Escaping Difference in swift 4

### @Non-escaping

1.Non-escaping Is Default .

2.Pass the closure as Functions.

3.Function Before Returns  @non-escaping Closure gets Called.

4.No Longer exists In the Memory.

5.Compiler knows the @non-escaping Closure Handle memory allocation. It will 
   take care About memory.

6.Must and should Provide [Weak self] while calling function.Its safe.Because 
    of  @non-escaping closure gets called Before Function Returns.

### @escaping

1 escaping Is not Default . Swift 1X ,2X @escaping is Default.

2.Pass the closure as Functions.

3.Function Returns After @escaping Closure gets Called.

4.@escaping Closure Memory exists while Execution.

5.Outside of the function  @escaping closure also Executed.

6.Most Of the Developer Think Point No -3 in @escaping How to call @escaping closure after function Returns. Actually code called top to bottom think this 
top to bottom means like a **.Sync**. But In our Case works **.Async**.

If You Don't Know About **.Sync** And **.Async**.

**.Sync** means One By One its executed.

**.Async**. Randomely Executed. So Function Returns After @escaping closure
 Executed.